Не работает \n при отправке сообщений telegram bot
В файле лежит одна строка:
Яблочный десерт\n\n 00:00 Приготовление запеченных яблок\n\n • В видео рассказывается о приготовлении запеченных яблок с корицей, соленой карамелью, сливочным муссом и копченой грушей.\n• Для приготовления... 

Последовательность действий такова:

Считываю все строки из файла методом System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()

string[] desertsTexts = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("../../../Recipes/Texts/DesertsText.txt");


Присваиваю переменной text первую (нулевую) строку

text = desertsTexts[0];


Отправляю в чат сообщение, передавая методу SendTextMessageAsync как параметр text

await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    chat.Id,
    text
);

Результат работы метода на скриншоте:

То есть буквально не работает символ переноса строки \n
Как сделать так, чтобы он отработал как надо?

Это не символ переноса строки, а символ обратной косой черты и буковка n. Если вы хотите символ переноса строки, значит выполните замену этих двух символов на символ переноса строки

А, я понял в чём моя ошибка. Спасибо
Я пытался поправить ситуацию методом Replace("\n", "\n")...

Replace("\\n", "\n")

Но вообще для лучшего результата и универсальности, возможно, стоит использовать что-то вроде Regex.Unescape (но я в своём гyгле почему-то не могу найти метод, который вёл бы себя идентично строковым литералам)
